# AWS Amplify - React Vite - jpeg image not loading

Tags: reactjs, vite, aws-amplify

I have a react app that uses vite. I am hosting via AWS Amplify. In my app (built with vite), I have three images stored in the `public` directory. One of the three images (image_1.jpeg) loads locally but it does not load after being deployed. The other two (background.jpg and logo.png) are working fine.

```
my_app/
├─ public/
|  ├─ assets/
|  |  ├─ images/
|  |  |  ├─ image_1.jpg
|  |  |  ├─ image_2.jpeg
├─ src/
|  ├─ pages/
|  |  ├─ Home.tsx

etc...
```

Home.tsx

```
...
<img src="./assets/images/image_1.jpg" /> @* this image works fine *@
<img src="./assets/images/image_2.jpeg" /> @* this imsage doesn't work *@
...
```

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/2849), I was able to solve my issue. In my app settings in AWS Amplify, I had to update an existing rewrite.

Old source value:
`</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>`

New source value:
`</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|jpeg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>`

[image]